# Возврат значения по URL из AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Привет всем, я скопипастил себе код для вызова URL, вызов срабатывает, но обработку возвращаемого значения сделать не получается.

```
function updateSalesOrders()
{
var guid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()

$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            croosDomain: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 100000,
            url: "http://link" + guid,
            data: "",
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",                 
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "myCallback",
            success: function (response){
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (request, thrownError) {
                alert("Ошибка выполнения запроса:\n" + request + "\nОшибка:\n" + thrownError);
                }
        });
}
```

Сейчас я получаю ошибку parseerror.
Из URL возвращается ответ в таком формате:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">ответ</string>
```

Как мне его принять и обработать?
Я подозреваю, что мне нужен не jsonp, но что? И как прописать?

Comment: папиши полный текст ошибки

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan при выводе thrownError у меня только "parseerror". Можно из thrownError еще что-то достать?

Comment: @IvanMaslov а там не `xml` случайно ?)

Comment: ты запрос куда делаешь? если на другой сервер то надо четко знать какой тип ответа он тебе возвращает ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych вполне возможно. Как обработать возврат xml?

Comment: @IvanMaslov `dataType: "xml"`, а дальше уже чето думать

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan запрос я делаю в свое приложение, там возвращается тупо string. Я вообще не понимаю откуда остальное берется

Comment: на серверной части до возврата сделай `json_encode` ответа, потом отправь ответ в `front`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych на это у меня просто error

Comment: @IvanMaslov надо смотреть что сервер делает с ответом...

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan проще будет обработать xml

Comment: что у тебя на серверной стороне? `php`? или что то другое?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ASP.NET приложение на IIS 8.5

Comment: Сделай там `string XML="<note><body>Message content</body></note>"; ; return new StringContent(XML, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")` просто для примера.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan `{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/xml; charset=utf-8"]}]}`

Comment: @IvanMaslov ну значит ошибки больше нет верно?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan на сервере не разворачивал еще, не знаю как захавает это. Вообще в той строке значения-то не вижу